# How do I resolve unaligned boxes in grid-area

Tags: css, alignment, css-grid

I'm working on a personal portfolio project currently and I've met some errors I'm having difficulty solving. I was doing fine with the furniture page alignment, but when it comes to accessories.html, the tools.jpg and decorative-accents.jpg are not aligned properly even tho they are the same proportionate height  and width (i took into account the gap and borders they have to cross) as the other images.  I tried all the align and justify properties but none worked, nor did using grid rows and columns. Did I get the image sizes wrong? Would appreciate if an expert can help resolve this issue.

Link to the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/helloyellowmellowcello/WareHouse_FurnitureRetail/tree/Redesign_%231

```
.product__list {
 display: grid;
  min-width: 1189px;
  grid-template-areas: 'fabric fabric organisation'
                     'mirrorsclocks mirrorsclocks organisation'
                     'bedroom bathroom dining-room'
                     'kitchen decorativeaccents patio'
                     'lighting decorativeaccents tools';
  /*grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);*/
}

#fabric {
  grid-area: fabric;
  /*grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;*/
}

#organisation {
  grid-area: organisation;
  max-height: 731px;
  /*grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;*/
}

#decorativeaccents {
  grid-area: decorativeaccents;
  max-height: 731px;
  /*grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;*/
}

#lighting {
  grid-area: lighting;
 /*grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 5 / 6;*/
}

 #mirrorsclocks {
  grid-area: mirrorsclocks;
  /*grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;*/
}

#bedroom {
  grid-area: bedroom;
  /*grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;*/
}

#bathroom {
  grid-area: bathroom;
  /*grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;*/
}

#dining-room {
  grid-area: dining-room;
  /*grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;*/
}

#kitchen {
  grid-area: kitchen;
  /*grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;*/
}

#patio {
  grid-area: patio;
  /*grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;*/
}

#tools {
  grid-area: tools;
  /*grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 5 / 6;*/
}
```

Comment: It looks you have comment out to much of your code.
Either you use the grid template solution and then you need:
grid-template-columns, grid-template-rows, grid-template-areas.

..or your set every grid individual as you have done in your commented code.

Please create a code snippet or a share link to a website where code is reachable.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D I have already provided the link to the github repo in my above post. It is open to the public and you can download the entire repo which includes the code: https://github.com/helloyellowmellowcello/WareHouse_FurnitureRetail/tree/Redesign_%231   The reason why I didn't post the entire code snippet is because it involves a separate html file, and several images in a file that I've linked within the html file (the problem could be the image size itself. Idk what is the root cause tht's why I'm asking). The css code is the shortest that's why I've posted here in my qn.

Comment: @Toolbox : I have already provided the link to the github repo in my above post. It is open to the public and you can download the entire repo which includes the code: https://github.com/helloyellowmellowcello/WareHouse_FurnitureRetail/tree/Redesign_%231   The reason why I didn't post the entire code snippet is because it involves a separate html file, and several images in a file that I've linked within the html file (the problem could be the image size itself. Idk what is the root cause tht's why I'm asking). The css code is the shortest that's why I've posted here in my qn.

Comment: We shouldn't have to download anything to recreate the issue for you. You can always use placeholder images. Again, if we can't reproduce the issue from the code **in the actual question** we can't diagnose it. **Help us help you**... * Provide a demo using Stack Snippets*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why there were extra whitespace. Some elements in the main__nav was using the same id as those in the #main content, so the solution is to simply rename the category blocks #lighting and #tools into another unique id.